I was given a used road bike, should I be concerned about the age of the frame, and can I replace it and reuse the other parts?
A neighbour gave me a road bike, it's a 2007 Condor Squadra from "Condor Cycles". It's a aluminium/carbon frame with Campagnolo Chorus group set, 10 speed 11/25t cassette with 50/36t chainrings.
Wheels are Campagnolo 700c DPRO Zonda with 15mm inner width.
It's a nice bike, the previous owner said that it's been ridden on alpine tours events and group rides but not much more than that and thinks that it should be OK to ride.
The frame is a large size with what looks like 180mm cranks.
Should I be concerned about the age of the frame? I mean it's seventeen years old.
If I wanted to replace the frame with a medium size one, what frame would take the Campagnolo Chorus group set?  I mean everything including bottom bracket, assuming is part of the group set.
Would a normal road bike frame be able to accommodate all it's Campy components?
Attached are some photos.








First question that comes to mind: Did you ride it? and how did it feel?
If it feels good, there's no need to change anything. The age as such is not an issue.

Next question is  - does this bike meet your needs? What kind of riding will you do?

@DavidD, Yes in the sense that my teenagers are interest and it's a way of introducing them to the experience of riding a fast road bike, assuming Campy group sets are built for speed and it's an opportunity to learn more about cycling componentry and maintenance.

Well, any road bike group set can handle the speeds an average road cyclist can reach. What makes you fast is not the bike, it's the body powering it...

@MindDBike If you are introducing someone to cycling it's best to match the bike to the type of riding to maximize the positive first experience. If the interest is fast road riding then great - it's a match. If they really want to do something else this bike could be an exercise in frustration.

The bike is not good. Give it to me, I know how to dispose of it properly!

My bike is probably 40 years old!  Admittedly I haven't ridden it a lot in the last few years, but I put over 1000 miles on it in 1999.

The frame you have here is of a very good quality, high grade italian aluminium tubing, smooth welds and manufactured in Italy for Condor (as far as I could tell).
The frame will ride very well: most of these have a high front end giving a more upright and comfortable ride than a typical road/race bike and the carbon rear triangle also contributes to the comfort by absorbing road vibration.
The main downside is that a tyre wider than 25mm is not a fit for the frame: it's a fast endurace bike suitable for longer rides on nice roads.
The campagnolo components feature alot of carbon and you may be surprised how much they fetch when sold individually at online auction. It is high quality equipment. The cassette can be changed to 12-29 and the inner chainring to 34t to give better hillclimb gears. With such a light bike, it is more than sufficient.
If you wish to transplant a new frame, you may find some of the campagnolo assembly unusual if you are not familiar with it: the chainset particularly is not straightforward and note you must use Campagnolo-type gear cables as Shimano-type cables have a larger head and cause problems, do not try!. This frame uses shallow drop brakes, BSC (British) threaded bottom bracket and standard 130/100mm OLD wheels, quite standard specifications until disc brakes became default. But unless you have the tooling/confidence/knowledge, you may be paying someone else to do part of it. And the benefit? Probably not such a good frame but perhaps in a better size, for alot of work.

As you said, at the time it was built it was a high end bike.
Since I don't have the right tools for a Campy group set, I decided to do the minimum amount of work to bring it to rideable condition and buy second hand tools if I need them. This way it will be kept original and a reflection of it's era.
I can take it to a couple of outdoor velodromes open to the public.
It's the riding experience on an old spec bike that would be something to look forward to.  Thanks again to everyone's contribution, I can't wait to get my hands on it.

@MindDBike There are specialist commercial services eg TheSeatpostMan that can remove the stuck seatpost without damaging the frame, if it comes to that. Carbon posts in Alu are tricky.

Metal and carbon fiber doesn’t magically go bad after 17 years if it’s stored in a dry place away from the sun.
You might need to replace:

Rubber parts: Tyres, brake pads
Possibly brake cable housings
Grease in bearings (if they can be serviced)

Exchanging the frame is quite time consuming. You can’t go to a proper modern frame(set) because modern frames have thru axles and hydraulic disc brakes. What you need is a typical frame from around ~2010 for rim brakes and 130mm wide rear hub with quick release skewer. You might need a different diameter seatpost and headset bearings (often included in a frameset) but everything else should be standard stuff.
Personally I wouldn’t invest the time and money, especially not in an outdated bike and with gearing as hard as yours (is that an 11–25t cassette and 50/36t chainrings?).

Also my opinion: while I don't think that good rim brakes are a deal breaker for a second hand bike, the gearing is, especially for a bike that is not meant to be raced - and even if it were, the gearing would probably unsuited with the current understanding of race dynamics (clearly a from a time where grinding was considered the right approach).

@Michael, Yes that is correct, it's a 11/25t cassette with 50/36t chainrings.
I've added another photo of the cassette.

To answer your last question first: I'm quite sure that there will be other frames which are able to take all the components from the current bike. You will have to search thoroughly to find one and don't overlook any parameter.
Concerning the age of the frame: if the frame did not have a crash or does not have any obvious damages, I would not care much about the age. 17 years isn't an age for a frame per se. Since a frame doesn't have any moving parts there's nothing to go bad just from getting older.
My personal opinion on the thing:
Before you replace the frame, either see if you can use it as it is (maybe with minor upgrades/changes to single components) or try and sell the bike as a whole and get another, better fitting one. Why? Because replacing the frame is the most invasive operation you can do to a bike since you have to remove and remount nearly every part of it. If you have a bike with expensive, hand-selected components this might be a good option. However, the components on your bike are rather standard now, so that it will not be worth the hassle of a rebuild unless you have some emotional connection with them - which you obviously not have since you got the bike from a neighbour.

This answer goes to history as the first time someone on this site claimed Campagnolo (and especially Chorus) not being expensive.

@ojs well, good point. However, to my (in terms of Campagnolo rather limited) knowledge, the Chorus group is at least currently the "cheapest" of the Campa road groupsets. If course this may still be on a high overall level...

At the time OP's bike was made, Chorus was the second highest tier Campagnolo group, had very little difference from Record, and around the same price point as Dura-Ace (unless the distributor for your country was ripping you off, in which case it was more expensive). Even now there is Centaur below Chorus level.

@Benedikt Bauer, Yes I could sell the bike but it would require some preparation as the carbon seat post is seized with the seat tube and cannot be adjusted, although I still haven't tried pouring boiling water on the seat tube yet and I suspect that he carbon steerer may also be seized with the stem.

@MindDBike: Well, you'll have to fix that in any case, no matter whether you sell the bike or use it yourself...

+1 to all of this. If the OP is really contemplating a frame transplant, bear in mind that there are a lot of interface points between parts and the frame, and multiple standards for every one of them.
